# Projects not compiling [Neither in Eclipse nor in NetBeans]

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I reset my System lately because it had been fixed [hardware wise] and I gave it out of hand. 
I had to reinstall Eclipse and saved my Projects so I could recover them when Im back on track. 
I imported the project via: File -> Import -> General -> File System -> My Directory & Project.
Seemed to be fine, it had been the whole project folder with the .settings, bin, src, .classpath, .project, _classpath & _project Folders/files.

So i hit run  in Eclipse but nothing seemed to happen.
Its an Application with an GUI so there should be at least a frame showing, but i couldnt sort it out. 
Only thing happening is that there is Process called: Java(TM) Platform SE binary which costs a sufficent amount of CPU power...

So I decided to try NetBeans instead (friend of mine told me it may work) - but its the same again. The console just prints out run: 
and nothing else.

What to do? Im new to programming so i got no real clue whats going on. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you create a new project and copy your source files to the `src` folder ?

Comment: Didnt work, seems to be a problem with the configuration because new projects compile without problems.

Comment: I really can't understand your actual problem . If all fails go back to stupid way :P Create new project , create `.java` files of same names and copy paste the code . Btw just saying , NetBeans generates extra files (eg `.form` files for easy `swing` desiging ) for IDE purpose, if those are lost it is hard to bring it back to original state .

Comment: Cool cos stupid way was not working either (copying the source code led to the exact same end). I rewrote the important parts manually, did work . Ridiciulous.